# How to validate if underline is included or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I want to validate if "_"(underline) is included or not in "name" column.
e.g. test_person is ok but testperson is not ok.

What I already tried: 
1.

```
validates :name, inclusion: { in: %w(_), message: "Invalid name %{value}. Name must be firstname_familyname" }
```

Then I couldn't save any names doesn't matter with or without underline, e.g. test_person and testperson were rejected and shown an error massage "Invalid name....".

2.

```
validates :name, format: { With: /\A[a-zA-Z]+_+[a-zA-Z]+\z/ }
```

Then ArgumentError was shown.

Can someone let me know how underline can be validated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format

```
validates :name, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+_+[a-zA-Z]+\z/, message: "name must include underscore" }
```

The only issue with your code is - you have `With:` with capital `W`

Change it with above line `with:`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. The problem was solved now!!  
Do you know how can I write with "inclusion"? 
I would like to know out of pure curiosity.